# Trouble transforming column in Julia DataFrame based on condition on rows

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am wondering what I am doing wrong with this conditional `transform` in `Julia's` `DataFrames`. I tried going with the examples [here](https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial/blob/master/05_columns.ipynb) but somehow could not translate the instructions to write a function that transforms the rows it needs to.

My code:

```
function cleaner(name,cc)
    if name == "svietnam" 
        "DRV" 
    elseif name == "vietnam" 
        "RVN"  
    else
        Missing
    end

end
formal_long_vietnamcleaned = transform(formal_long, [:name, :country_code] => cleaner => :cleaned_cc )
```

Somehow, the string comparison does not work. When I tried it to check whether the strings exist in the table with

`formal_long_vietnamcleaned[formal_long_vietnamcleaned.name .== "svietnam",:]` I definitely got matches. Somehow, I do not understand how to write a useful function for `transform`. I would appreciate your guys help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `ByRow(cleaner)` since without, `name` and `cc` will be the entire columns (vectors), so what's happening is something like `["svietnam"] == "svietnam"` which is obviously false. `ByRow` applies the function row-wise so that the function gets the individual elements of each column.

Also, `missing` should be lowercased.